# Linq to Entities To Column names

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, linq-to-entities

I am relatively new to Linq to Entities but I am making good progress. One item I haven’t been able to figure out yet is how to extract the columns names from the database. For example in the code below I would like to replace the constants with the field names from the database.

I haven't been able to get the answers I've seen eleswhere to work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Bob

```
DataTable dtNPRS = new DataTable();

const string kInitDate = "NPR_Init_Date";
const string kActive = "Active";
const string kStatusId = "NPR_Status_Id";

try
{
    DataRow drNPR;

    var nprs = (from n in db.FMCSA_NPR
                join u in db.FMCSA_USER  on n.CREATED_BY equals u.ID
                join t in db.LKUP_NPR_TYPE  on  n.NPR_TYPE_ID equals t.ID
                join s in  db.LKUP_AUDIT_STATUS on  n.NPR_STATUS_ID equals s.ID
                where n.ROLE_ID == pRoleId && n.OWNER_ID == pOwnerId
                      && n.NPR_STATUS_ID == pNPRStatusId && n.ACTIVE == pActive
                select n).ToList();

    if (nprs.Count() == 0)
       return null;

    //  / build the table structure we need
    dtNPRS.Columns.Add(kInitDate, typeof(DateTime));
    dtNPRS.Columns.Add(kActive,typeof(bool));
    dtNPRS.Columns.Add(kStatusId,typeof(Int32));

    foreach (var npr in nprs)
    {
       drNPR = dtNPRS.NewRow();
       drNPR[kInitDate] = npr.NPR_INIT_DATE;
       drNPR[kActive] = npr.ACTIVE;
       drNPR[kStatusId] = npr.NPR_STATUS_ID;
       dtNPRS.Rows.Add(drNPR);
    }

    return dtNPRS;
}
```

Comment: **Why on earth** are you accessing your data with an ORM like Entity Framework, but then converting it back to rows/columns in your program?? That doesn't make any sense at all...... **either** stay with classic ADO.NET and using DataTable/DataRow, **or** switch to EF and then use **objects** - not rows&columns in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to convert a LINQ entity to a DataTable dynamically is to use Reflection to get the names:

```
var props = typeof(FMCSA_NPR).GetProperties();
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    dtNPRS.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
}
```

And a similar process for updating the rows:

```
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    dtNPR[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(npr, null);
}
```

EDIT: TO handle Nullable, do:

```
if (prop.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
    var type = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

HTH.

Comment: This sure looked promising but it fails of the first nullable field trying to retrieve PropertyType. The exception is [System.NotSupportedException] = {"DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>."}. Most of my fields are nullable

Comment: OK, then you'd have to detect if its a Nullable<>, and then use the GetGenericArguments()[0] method to get the inner type.

Comment: Brian, Thanks once again. I cannot figure out the exact syntax I need to get this code to work. prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0] does not seems to work.

Comment: Added comment; using approach above, this should work; it won't work if it's not a generic type.

Comment: That was close, I had to change the if to:   if (prop.PropertyType.UnderlyingSystemType.Name == "Nullable`1")

Comment: *"The only way to convert a LINQ entity to a DataTable dynamically is to use Reflection to get the names"*; not true.  You can use expression trees to get the column names (that's how the ORM does it in the first place!).

Comment: Dynamically?  I know you can build a tree, but reflection can inspect the metadata dynamically, I wasn't aware that expressions could extract a class's metadata...  With the ORM, this all is typically code-generated...